# function pointer prototype which takes three integer pointers as arguments and returns character pointer

Tags: c, pointers

This was asked in a written test of an interview :
Question: write a function pointer prototype which takes three integer pointers as arguments and returns character pointer.

My answer:

```
char (*funct_ptr) (int *a, int *b, int *c);
```

This was marked wrong. Can anyone please help me with the right answer to this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your prototype is declared to return a character, not a character pointer.

To make the returned thing to a pointer, add `*`.

```
char* (*funct_ptr) (int *a, int *b, int *c);
```